# MySQL Query only returning 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm having a problem with my MySQL query. It has only been displaying the first result from a list of data from a variable. Here is what I've got

```
$Data='1,2,3'

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM data WHERE uid IN ($Data) ");

if (mysql_num_rows($fetch)) {
    $emaildata = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch);
    foreach($emaildata as $fetch2){
        echo $fetch2;
    }
} else {
    echo Failed;
}
```

Now, it only pulls the first result of the 3 instead of each of the 3's separate emails. Any help is appreciated, kinda new to this whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Use as below because you have iterate `$fetch` through while loop which is easier

```
while($emaildata = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
   echo  $emaildata['email']
}
```

Recommendations:

1.Learn to prevent from MySQL Injections: [Good Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

2.Mysql extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. More reading: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 3):

Fetch array instead of fetching associative, and use `mysqli_()` instead of `mysql_()` which is no longer maintained by the community, also use `while` loop instead of `foreach` and use `index` name if any

```
while($emaildata = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
     echo $emaildata; //Use index name if any
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use while loop, which enables you to iterate so long as there is a next row with this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($fetch)){
      echo  $row['email']
 }
```

CAUTION!!!: use `mysqli_fetch_row` as `mysql_fetch_row` is deprecated